# Use placeholder as value for @Header in an argument in a Service Activator

Tags: spring-integration

We have parametrised the headers names in a Spring boot app, in the YAML and I have a Service Activator with a method with 2 arguments, where the first argument should be the value of one of the message headers.

How can I use the value of a placeholder as the Header name in the Header annotation ?

`public void setTotal(@Header("${rip.headers.batchno.name}") String batchId) {`

This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders (and SpEL expressions) are not supported there.

If you open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) we can consider adding support.